# How can I background the R process in ESS / Emacs?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I often run long R scripts when I start my R environment. I would like to be able to load / run the R script in Emacs / ESS and continue other work in another buffer.

When I press C-g or C-c C-c the process is interrupted, and I must restart the script.

What is the best way to background the R process in ESS / Emacs?

EDIT: Thank you for your answers and comments, but none of them address the fact that Emacs freezes when you load / run a large script and you can't change buffer.

I suppose my question is a little more general - can Emacs background a process to let you keep working?

Comment: use C-c C-l to execute the script.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ESS runs R as asynchronous process. You don't need to background anything. You can run your code for hours and still work in ESS uninterrupted.

Your problem seems to be something else. When you execute your script you do it "visibly", i.e. your executed code is printed to the terminal. This cause Emacs to freeze.

Set `ess-eval-visibly` to nil and  huge chunks of code will be sent to R instantly:

```
(setq ess-eval-visibly nil)
```

Cheers.

### Update

There is a new setting for `ess-eval-visibly` in recent versions of ESS - 'nowait. It places your code in an inferior buffer and then sends it to the subprocess. In this way you can see your code  and all the output afterwards without waiting for the subprocess to finish.

Comment: If you end up in a different ess environment where you can't/don't want to evaluate and emacs lisp, you can achieve the same result by making sure that your function is assigning its result to a variable. Instead of `long.running()` do `res <- long.running()`.

Comment: Small update: As of ESS version 12.09-1, ` ess-eval-visibly-p` is now deprecated.  Should use `ess-eval-visibly`. See: http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html.

Answer (score 3):

`M-x R` will start an R session (the default buffer name is `*R*`). If your press `M-x R` again, a second R session will be started (with buffer name `*R:2*`).

Each session has its own R process, so you can run a long R script in one and still use the other independently.

Pressing `C-x C-b` brings up the buffer list, which would allow you to switch between R sessions.

Or, if you put

```
(global-set-key "\C-cr" 'ess-request-a-process)
```

in your `.emacs` initialization file, then every time you press `C-c r` you will be prompted for which R session (buffer) you wish to switch to. If you only have one session, it will switch there automatically.

Comment: There's already a binding for `ess-request-a-process` C-c C-k, but for some peculiar and completely unknown reason it defaults to "S", even if you set "R" as default.

Answer (score -3):

In my personal experience, ESS isn't very good at handling very large scripts, in that at times the rest of Emacs becomes unusable. Perhaps you are better off doing development in ESS, then running the full script in BATCH mode.