# emacs not responsive while ess evaluate code

Tags: emacs, ess

I want to know if there is a configuraiton option to let me continue edit my R script after I send a code chunk for ess to evaluate (using C+RT).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't use ESS but does emacs freezes all together or just the ESS buffer?

Comment: emacs freezes too.

Comment: Look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770523/8544157) for your answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I background the R process in ESS / Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770523/how-can-i-background-the-r-process-in-ess-emacs)

Answer (score 1):

You want to customize `ess-eval-visibly`. Set it to either `nil` or `'nowait`, depending on what you want.

When `nil`, ESS won't print the input. When `'nowait`, ESS prints the input but doesn't wait for the process to finish before doing so.